# Ansible Message Output based on task result

Tags: ansible

Is it possible in Ansible to display different messages based on a result of the task?

For example

```
 - name: check_prometheus_status_kafka
    shell: /usr/sbin/ss -lnt|awk '{ print $4}'|grep 9071 |sed 's/\*//'| sed 's/\://'
    register: prom_status
    tags:
      - check_prometheus_status_kafka

  - name: post_message_prom_kafka
    debug: msg="Prometheus for Kafka listening in {{ prom_status.stdout }}"
    when: prom_status.stdout == "9071"
    tags:
      - post_message_prom_kafka
```

What I want is an additional message which would output something like `Prometheus for Kafka is NOT listening on port {{ prom_status.stdout }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but here is something for your consideration (play with the value of `actual_port`):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    port_to_listen_on: "9071"
    actual_port: "9071"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Prometheus for Kafka {{ (actual_port == port_to_listen_on) | ternary ('', 'NOT ') }}listening in {{ port_to_listen_on }}"

    # or

     - debug:
         msg: "Prometheus for Kafka {{ 'NOT ' if (actual_port != port_to_listen_on) else '' }}listening in {{ port_to_listen_on }}"
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. What I want to accomplish is to provide a message regardless of outcome, but message must be compiled based on task result. For example, if job is successful, I want to say "SUCCESSFUL", and if it a failure I want to post message "FAILED", just like 'else' clause.

Comment: So adapt the messages from the answer I provided. What else remains unclear?

Comment: Thanks so much @techraf!!

Comment: I needed this solution: Can you please explain each item in your code like what is ternary? my question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59076323/how-to-handle-fail-and-pass-in-ansible-message-with-when